# SQLite: Leave only n rows for each field

Tags: sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table

```
+-----------------------------+---------------+-----------+
|         Painter             | Painting      | Rate      |
+-----------------------------+---------------+-----------+
|  Zinaida Serebriakova       | Window        | 5         |
|  Zinaida Serebriakova       | Florence      | 1         |
|  Zinaida Serebriakova       | Nude          | 8         |
|  Zinaida Serebriakova       | Bath          | 4         |
|  Thomas And William Daniell | Turbine Makers| 2         |
|  Thomas And William Daniell | George Iain   | 7         |
|  Thomas And William Daniell | Flax Pullers  | 3         |
|  Robert Motherwell          | Galleons      | 1         |
|  Robert Motherwell          | Ulysses       | 2         |
+-----------------------------+---------------+-----------+
```

I need to get 2 paintings for each painter with the highest rate.

```
+-----------------------------+---------------+-----------+
|         Painter             | Painting      | Rate      |
+-----------------------------+---------------+-----------+
|  Zinaida Serebriakova       | Nude          | 8         |
|  Zinaida Serebriakova       | Window        | 5         |
|  Thomas And William Daniell | George Iain   | 7         |
|  Thomas And William Daniell | Flax Pullers  | 3         |
|  Robert Motherwell          | Ulysses       | 2         |
|  Robert Motherwell          | Galleons      | 1         |
+-----------------------------+---------------+-----------+
```

And delete everything else!

Comment: Assume "Bath" have rating 5, not 4. So "Nude" is 8, "Bath" and "Window" are 5 each... what record must be deleted - "Bath" or "Window"? and why?

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT author, 
                name, 
                rating, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY author 
                                    ORDER BY rating DESC ) rn
         FROM ratings )
DELETE
FROM ratings
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM cte
               WHERE ratings.author = cte.author
                 AND ratings.name = cte.name
                 AND cte.rn > 2 );
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cZjetohXFUJAcRQawnvTKw/0)

Answer (score 1):

Another version using `row_number()` window function (And thus needing sqlite 3.25 or newer):

```
DELETE FROM ratings
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid
                FROM (SELECT rowid
                           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY painter ORDER BY rate DESC) AS rn
                      FROM ratings)
                WHERE rn > 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python script.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("YOUR_DB.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Select painters with number of its occurance
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Painter, COUNT(*) FROM Paintings GROUP BY PainterORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC"

# Get only artists with occurance greater than N
data = [artist[0] for artist in selected_data if artist[1] > 150]

while data:

    # One by one get artists and select N-th max rate
    artist = data.pop(0)
    sql = "SELECT Champ51 FROM Paintings WHERE Champ1 = ? ORDER BY Champ51 DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 149"
    selected_data = cursor.execute(sql, [artist]).fetchall()
    last = selected_data[0][0]

    # Delete rate less than N-th
    sql = "DELETE FROM Paintings WHERE Champ1 = ? AND Champ51 < ?"
    cursor.execute(sql, [artist, last])
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: Data operations must be performed on the database server side using proper query.

Comment: Where do `Champ1`, `Champ51`, and this 150 magic number come from? And why the `DISTINCT`?